# Populating and validating a bean

Tags: validation, jsp, servlets

I'd like to know that if it's possible to populate a bean and - assuming every property is type of String - validate that none of the properties are null or empty?

As far as I researched, populating the bean is easy with **BeanUtils**, but I couldn't really find a solution for the validation part. Based on the user's previous selection, the populating could target a lot of bean types, but checking each property by hand destroys the advantage I gain. The only option that I see right now is using reflection but I'd like to avoid it if possible.

Some pseudocode:

```
<choose vehicle>
<fill in form data>
   <if car>
      <auto populate carBean>
      <check every property by hand>
   <if boat>
      <auto populate boatBean>
      <check every property by hand>
   ...
```

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Edit 1: I forgot to mention that the form is on a JSP page, the data is processed by a servlet, and the beans are entities (POJOs).

Comment: Looks like you came to a point you understand JSP/Servlet well enough that it's time to look for a real servlet based MVC framework to save boilerplate code. Examples are JSF and Spring MVC. Both have transparent support for Bean Validation as well as Bean Population.

Comment: Which one would you recommend? Spring looks more popular, while JSF seems friendlier for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using Bean Validation API (`javax.validation` package) with annotations like `@NotNull`. Not very easy to configure, but may be useful.

Comment: Are these annotations evaluated when the bean gets populated with data?

Comment: Okay, thanks, I'll read about it. I'm going to wait a bit for any other suggestions, if there are none to come I'll accept your answer. :)